# cmd from R with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: r, cmd

I am trying to use `wkhtmltopdf` to turn website content into pdf and then read it into my R. So I write in my COMMAND PROMPT line to download as html front page of yahoo finance (just for fun). So i create "TemporaryFolder" on my C and write in cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin>wkhtmltopdf https://finance.yahoo.com/ "C:/TemporaryFolder/myhtml.pdf"
```

And it downloads yahoo finance website as pdf. Now I want to do the same thing but using R script. I know there is `system` function however I have very little experience with it (and with cmd to be honest).

So now i try use this command in my Rstudio so I can later create R script which downloads website as html and converts it to pdf.

```
URL="https://finance.yahoo.com/"
wkhtmltopdf_dir="C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin"
save_as="C:/TemporaryFolder/myhtml.pdf"
x=paste0(wkhtmltopdf_dir,">","wkhtmltopdf"," ",URL," ",'\"',save_as,'\"')
system(x)
```

I also tried `shell(x)` but I got "permission denied".

But it does nothing... Could someone elaborate how `system` works and what should be added here?

BTW: can I harm my computer by using `system`? For example writing some "bad" command? This question might sound silly, but I am really to new to this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to paste as a command (`"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin>wkhtmltopdf https://finance.yahoo.com/ \"C:/TemporaryFolder/myhtml.pdf\""`) doesn't quite work. The first part (`"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin>`) is actually the prompt when you run it in commander. It's not a part of the command, but instead shows in which directory you are running that command.

If you replace `wkhtmltopdf` with `C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`, it should work just fine:

```
URL="https://finance.yahoo.com/"
wkhtmltopdf_exe="C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"
save_as="C:/TemporaryFolder/myhtml.pdf"
x=paste0(wkhtmltopdf_exe," ",URL," ",'\"',save_as,'\"')
system(x)
```

To answer your second question, a call to `system()` runs the command through CMD. So basically anything you could mess up through CMD.exe, you can mess up through `system()`.

Comment: Thank you for quick response and explaining a little bit about how prompt actually works. I tried your code, but it still did nothing... my `C:/TemporaryFolder/` is still empty after running this code. However when I do `y=system(x)` with your code `y` is `127` for some reason...

Comment: hmm, `127` as an errorcode usually means file-not-found. Can you confirm the name of the executable for the command `wkhtmltopdf` is `C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe` ?

Comment: I tried with `shell` instead of `system`. I recently red it should they work same way for most cases (is that true btw?). It returned me error: `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. Is this same error as `127`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. As i posted in comment, after using `shell(x)` instead of `system(x)` it returned `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. So I reinstalled my wkhtmltopdf to folder which name contains no spaces. So `wkhtmltopdf_exe` is now:

`wkhtmltopdf_exe="C:/Programs/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"`

Rest of the code is the same. Followup here would be nice, is there any way to workaround spaces in folder names? Or should I always avoid spaces? Putting wkhtmltopdf path into quotation marks didnt help.

Thank for user JAD for fixing my first code